# I'm getting the Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'addListener')

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I already included the tabs permissions on the JSON file

```js
    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, tab) => {
      if (tab.url && tab.url.includes("youtube.com/watch"))
        console.log("Hello")
    });
  }
});
```